# php simple html dom and iframe src

Tags: php, dom, iframe, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');
    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html('https://www7.fmovies.se/film/hometown-hero.m2r28/6xpjrp');
    foreach($html->find('div[id=player]') as $div)
    {
     foreach($div->find('iframe') as $iframe)
       {
             echo $iframe->src;

       }
    }
```

This is my code and as you see I'm trying to get the src of the iframe under the player div using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, can you explain to me why I'm getting a blank page as a result? 
Thanks!

UPDATE: After using a javascript switcher addon and disabling javascript, I noticed that the iframe I'm looking for is not loaded. What should I do to get the iframe src?

Comment: Go to that page, view the source and search for "<iframe". That's your first step to realizing what's going on here.

Comment: @pguardiario the iframe is loaded after a click which executes a javascript code that loads the iframe

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions;

1. Try to figure out how the javascript works, and mock this behavior in your PHP script.
2. Let the page load in, for example, selenium and then grab the SRC from the iframe using selenium. (https://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your reply, the iframe is loaded after a link click via javascript